# Pushing UIViewcontroller from a UIPanGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, uipresentationcontroller

I'm attempting to push a UIViewcontroller from the right by panning it across the screen proportional to a UIPanGesture across the screen.

Another way to say it is I want to push my UIViewcontoller on the Navigation Stack in the same way I am able to dismiss the UIViewcontroller from the Navigation Stack with a drag/pan .

I have some ideas, but there must be a proper approach to this.

Can someone push me in the right direction?

```
// No Code Snips
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to push a view controller with the pan gesture?

Comment: are you trying to create a right side burger menu?